# Was this brokers buying price real?

Tags: broker

I started to invest with a broker company without any knowledge about system how it works.
Is it possible that they shows me that they sold the shares for much higher price as was the High value indicated that day on the stock market?
Copy from the trade history:

| TRADE | TYPE | OPEN TIME | CLOSE TIME | SYMBOL | VOLUME | OPEN PRICE | CLOSE PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TR-1562531 | Live Buy market | 24.06.2022 15:20:31 | 24.06.2022 15:36:40 | PAYPAL | 100.00 | 70.81500 EUR | 78.21500 EUR |

In USD: the Open was 74.605, Close was  **82.401**

According the Market Insider Data Open-74.71, Close-77.68, Low-74.4  High-**78.66**

Can somebody check if such a Sell/Buy was real, please? Your advice will help me a lot in the decision how to deal with them.

Comment: I'm not following what you're asking. Can you try to clarify what happened and why you think it was wrong? In many countries brokerages are pretty well regulated, what country/brokerage does this pertain to?

Comment: are you sure the data you're looking at is in USD not EUR?

Comment: and: which broker is it? It is a bit shocking that you invest without knowing how it works because many scam companies like to ask you to invest without knowing how it works. A broker just does the trades you tell it to. If it did a trade, that you didn't tell it to, it's not a broker.

Comment: You "trade history" looks strange - it doesn't show you what price you actaully traded at? Or are they claiming they bought at 70.815 and sold for 78.215? This smells like a fake profit scam, where they ask you to "pay a fee" to retrieve your profit.

Comment: @DStanley I think it is showing the trade as a buy (at 15:20:31) + a sell (at 15:36:40)

Comment: Zoli would know if he bought and sold a stock which is what makes me think this is most likely a scam. This is not how trading works.

Comment: Agreed - this feels like "We traded for you and made $9,000. Just pay us $1,000 and we'll wire the profits to your account."

Comment: It may also be relevant that the _symbol_ for PayPal is **PYPL**, not PAYPAL as shown above.

Comment: Thank everybody for your opinion. The broker company name is BIT-Center operating from London. I was asked to pay a fee for "insider information", is this a standard for a broker? It seems to be a scam as some of you wrote. I found another web page with the same name.